# Sending out email from Linux VM instances

Tags: email, gcloud, google-workspace

Old linux user here; but only recently started using Google Cloud solutions to create a few VM instances running CentOS. Works great and have been using them for a few years successfully.

I am adding some new functions and I would like to be able to get emails that normally go to root to be sent to me.

In the past, I simply added a line in /etc/aliases at the end of

root:   myemail@gsuitedomain.com

This worked well as most of the boxes that I managed were inside a network where I also controlled the local mail server and could just send through it.

It appears that I need to setup some sort of relay using G-Suite?

Is that the right path?

Also, I really don't want to relay the email. I just want to send it to one of the G-Suite accounts. So, no real relaying needed.

Can someone direct me in the right direction for the easiest path to accomplish this?

Thank you for your help,

Tamer

Comment: Hey @Tamer Ziady, I don't understand the use case that you want to achieve here. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: very simple. For example on this linux VM instance I use several cron jobs to do all sorts of things. One of which is let's encrypt cron job to renew certs on websites that are running on the VM instance. 

These cron jobs currently pipe into root's mail box. 
2 problems that I am facing with these VM instances. 
1. None standard port blockage - easy enough to get around
2. I want to avoid running sendmail locally; but I will most likely have to or postfix to transfer mail out; but I just want to send to my account. In other words I don't need to send anywhere except 1 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP by default blocks all outbound traffic on port 25 so you have to use different one. [You can read about it in more detail in the GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

In my opinion you will have to run sendmail, postfix or anything else to send emails out but you have to configure them to some other port than 25.

Comment: thanks, that is a helpful start. I knew that they blocked ports on 25 to quench abuse. I was actually hopping someone would have written some code for Sendmail or Postfix to authenticate them to send mail via G-Suite in a similar way that WP-SMTP and other products do, using Google Developer API. That would be brilliant. Perhaps it is something that I may look into figuring out. I am sure many people would find it invaluable.